# Is it necessary to create an autorelease pool under ARC in GCD?

Tags: ios, memory-management, concurrency, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I have a run loop method for a CAEAGLLayer which uses GCD for serializing access to shared ivars.

My drawing code currently is constructed like this:

```
- (void)draw {
    dispatch_sync(serialDrawingQueue, ^{
        @autoreleasepool {
            [self drawingStart];

            [spriteA draw];
            [spriteB draw];

            [self drawingEnd];
        }
    });
}
```

The `draw` method is called by a CADisplayLink.
Is the `@autoreleasepool` necessary when I use GCD blocks?

Comment: How about you just try it and see if you get any "no pool in place…just leaking!" error messages?

Comment: Obviously it's better to ask more experienced developers wether or not this is a good idea.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html):

> If your block creates more than a few Objective-C objects, you might
>   want to enclose parts of your block’s code in an @autorelease block to
>   handle the memory management for those objects. **Although GCD
>   dispatch queues have their own autorelease pools**, they make no
>   guarantees as to when those pools are drained. If your application is
>   memory constrained, creating your own autorelease pool allows you to
>   free up the memory for autoreleased objects at more regular intervals.

Comment: More precisely see Quinn's response in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114025 - "If those blocks create autorelease traffic, that will only be released when the worker thread terminates, which can take a while if there’s work to be done" . Hence suggestion to use DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL_WITH_AUTORELEASE_POOL

Answer (score -1):

It seems that in iOS10 or higher dispatch queues no longer surround blocks by default in `@autoreleasepool`. This is indicated by `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL_WITH_AUTORELEASE_POOL` and `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT_WITH_AUTORELEASE_POOL` macros defined in [`queue.h`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/master/dispatch/queue.h#L543-L571)