# How to free memory after using NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: objective-c

I'm reading large json file from my iphone (file saved on iphone) using this code:

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

        // do something that takes a long time with receivedData here
        NSError* error;
        NSString *filePath = [self getFilePathWithName:LOCAL_JSON];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            HideHUD;
            DLog(@"Reading done");
            ShowMemoryUsageWithTitle(@"after reading json");

            return;
        });

        dict = nil;
    });
```

After I'm done with reading, memory usage has increased for 30 MB and for example total memory usage is 60 MB. After that I'm trying to read again and is 90 MB, and after that 120 MB. 
So conclusion is that memory is not autoreleasing. Every time I'm reading memory is increasing.I'm using ARC.

How can I free memory after I'm done with reading json file?

**UPDATE 1:**
Tried to put "hard" work inside @autoreleasepool {} but there was no changed with memory usage

**UPDATE 2:**
Tried without dispatch_async

**UPDATE 3:**
I've tried to use third part library like https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit but same problem. When I'm testing I'm triying only that thing, nothig else.

Comment: I think, your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586977/is-it-necessary-to-create-an-autorelease-pool-under-arc-in-gcd

Comment: You see that thing you call `dict`?  That has to be released somewhere (along with `jsonData` and possibly `filePath`).  If you are in a normal thread it will happen automatically via the autorelease mechanism, but if you're running your own thread you may be missing a suitable `@autorelease` boundary.

Comment: @HotLicks - Tried to put "hard" work inside autoreleasepool {} but there was no changed with memory usage

Comment: What precisely did you put "inside"?

Comment: @HotLicks - from NSError* error; and whole NSDictionary

Comment: Then use the Xcode tools to see who is tying up the memory.

Comment: @HotLicks - Tried without dispatch_async

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69564/discussion-between-croios-and-hot-licks).

Comment: Use the Xcode tools to see who is tying up the memory.

Comment: As @HotLicks has pointed out, you should be using the Leaks or Allocations templates of Instruments to diagnose this issue. Otherwise you are only guessing.

Comment: this line is problem, this line is increasing memory usage: NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

Comment: Yes, and that is expected. You are telling the JSON parser to take `jsonData`, parse it, and turn it into Foundation objects. This is what JSON parsers do. If you are giving it a lot of data, that is going to take a lot of memory. The memory you use in the heap is not as significant as the dirty VM pages, which you can see in Instruments. How *large* is the instance of `jsonData` you are passing?

Comment: 17 MB. But there is no logic that menery is increasing after every time more and more. I've out this code in Ibaction and that is how I'm testing that

Comment: Yes, there is logic. `-dataWithContentsOfFile:` returns an `NSData` instance that will load data from the file into a memory mapped buffer on demand. This is not efficient the way you are doing it. `+JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` is causing that `NSData` to hit the file over and over and not effectively reuse buffers. The `NSDictionary` returned from `NSJSONSerialization` is just a collection of pointers into those buffers. When you nil out the dictionary there is no effect on the pointers. Post your Instruments trace.

Comment: @quellish - The NSDictionary is not a collection of pointers into the NSData buffer, but is a bunch of separate objects in their own right.  No connection to the NSData object once parsing is complete.

Comment: @HotLicks absolutely it is. The values are pointers into the byte buffers. For example, `_newJSONValue()` finds byte offsets in the buffer that contain string keys (or values) and calls into `__newJSONString()`, which then creates `NSString` instances using `-initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone:`. At no point is the data that was read from the file *copied*. And, notably, the argument to freeWhenDone is `0x1`. You can see this yourself by looking at the assembly of Foundation or using Instruments.

Comment: maybe memory is not released because I'm testing on iphone simulator?

Comment: @quellish - Regardless, when the dictionary is released the NSData object would also be released.  So there would still be no accumulation of data.  And one could assure that new strings were allocated by using the NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves option, if one were really paranoid about it.

Comment: @HotLicks, the mutable leaves option does not influence wether new strings are allocated or not. It determines wether the value classes used are immutable (i.e. `NSString`) or mutable (i.e. `NSMutableString`). The values are allocated in the same way in both cases. The NSData object used by `+dataWithContentsOfFile:` is created using `-initWithBytes:length:copy:freeWhenDone:bytesAreVM:` after opening the file with `NSReadBytesFromFileWithExtendedAttributes`.Both make heavy use of VM and memory mapping. Releasing the `NSData` instance will not guarantee the buffers will be released immediately.

Comment: @CroiOS to answer your question you would need to at the very least post an Instruments trace.

Comment: @CroiOS, if I am reading your comment correctly you are saying that you are passing `NSJSONSerialization` 17 MB of `NSData`? And your application heap is increasing to 30MB, of which 13MB or so is the JSON, and 17 is the NSData?

Comment: @quellish - yes, but this 30 MB was cca. I've created IbAction so I'm clicking on button for this test. Every time I click on button memory is increased. So if I would click 10 times, memory would be increased from starting 15 MB to cca 315 MB (cca 30 MB for every click).

Comment: @CroiOS might I ask did you come to a solution for this?