# if i am using GCD should i need to create @autorelease pool

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch, nsautoreleasepool

i have read so many stackoverflow discussion about when to use @autorelease pool some one suggest to write own @autorelease pool when  create a secondary thread in your application and some discussion about this describe that you don't need to create @autorelease pool,
Also should i need to create externally @autorealease pool when i am using GCD

So please any one here , correct me about @autorelease for which scenario.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12587187/3541063) may answer your question.

Comment: See my answer updated for iOS 10+ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543034/285659)

Answer (score 0):

If your block creates more than a few Objective-C objects, you might want to enclose parts of your block’s code in an @autorelease block to handle the memory management for those objects.

Although GCD dispatch queues have their own autorelease pools, they make no guarantees as to when those pools are drained. If your application is memory constrained, creating your own autorelease pool allows you to free up the memory for autoreleased objects at more regular intervals.

So, if you are only allocating a few objects, don't worry about it.However, if you are allocating any significant number of objects (and since you are targeting a memory constrained environment), then you should be creating and draining pools.